# Get Value of Last Row In Table Using $(this) with Button Underneath

Tags: jquery, this

I've a table like this that opens up in a pop-up across my page (meaning many instances can occur of this on the page)

```
<table class="tab_logic">
<thead><th>#</th><th>SKU</th><th>Quantity</th></thead>
<tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

Directly underneath I have a button that dynamically adds rows on cick

```
<div class="actions><a id="add_row">Add Row</a></div>
```

Previously I was using this in my on click function for `add_row`

```
var num = $('.tab_logic tr:last td:first').text();
```

Worked great until I started to open up multiple pop-ups and my DOM started overlapping on the new pop-ups.

I believe my best solution is to use $(this) instead of relying on the DOM--

```
var num = $(this).parent().parent().find('td:first').text();
```

Got this far, but this seems to only bring back the first TR row in the table.
How do I modify this so that it always selects the parent (or closest going UP the dom as illustrated) of the LAST row/`TR` and first column/`TD`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use if the button is directly after the table.:

```
$(this).parent().prev().find('tr:last td:first').text();
```

If there is an element between the table and `.actions`, (such as the `
 tag below), you would need the code below.

```js
(function($) {
  $('#add_row').click(function () {
    var $this = $(this),
        num = $this.parent()
                .siblings('.tab_logic') // .prev() could also depending on the markup.
                .find('tr:last td:first').text();
                
    console.log(num);
  });
    
})(jQuery)
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="tab_logic" cellpadding="5px" border="1">
  <thead>
    <th>#</th>
    <th>SKU</th>
    <th>Quantity</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1. 1st</td>
      <td>1. 2nd</td>
      <td>1. 3rd</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2. 1st</td>
      <td>2. 2nd</td>
      <td>2. 3rd</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3. 1st</td>
      <td>3. 2nd</td>
      <td>3. 3rd</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<br>
<div class="actions"><a id="add_row">Add Row</a></div>
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you. Works perfect. Actually tried out your first response before the edit -- `$(this).parent().prev().find('tr:last td:first').text();` seems to be working fine as well, along with the new edit.

Comment: Your welcome. I encourage you to understand how this code works and ask any questions you might have. God bless :)